Trying to decide between Quarto and mdbook for a personal website+academic notes
I'm a newly employed academic in a third-world country who wants to host their lecture notes online. I'm going to go with GitHub Pages as the host and am trying to decide between mdbook and quarto as the host, for several reasons.
I specifically need the website to me as lightweight as possible, because a lot of the kids I'm going to be teaching are from rural areas, with most having not worked with a computer their entire lives. All they have are mobile phones with somewhat reliable 3G and 4G internet so I'd like the website to be

As lightweight as possible, so it can render on mobile devices

Have a template that allows downloading books as PDFs - this is one of the things that drew me towards mdbook, as it had that option built in.

Is fairly fast to compile when building on a local device (though my computer is fairly strong, so it shouldn't be a huge issue)

Has templates out-of-the-box that I can directly use for STEM notes, with the ability for multiple books that a user can access from the sidebar (this is my main problem with mdbook, I don't like the indexing)


I have a small mdbook setup but the main problem with mdbook that I have is that there is no built-in 'bookshelf' function - if possible, I'd like the students to have access to all of my notes on one website. The other thing I want is for my website to both serve as a personal portfolio and have notes - which specifically means that I'd like something like multiple non-numbered chapters between numbered chapters, which is something mdbook famously doesn't provide.
I've been looking into Quarto, and I wanted to ask people's opinions on Quarto because it seems like a more mature, out-of-the-box package that multiple frequently-visited websites use, but I'm not sure if it really satisfies my requirements. I'd rather commit to one thing because I can see this becoming a very long term project. The main problems I can see with Quarto is it being somewhat harder to use than mdbook, it adding a lot of unnecessary JS - as far as I can tell, mdbook websites tend to load extremely quickly on modern web browsers, and quarto websites are not quite as fast, though this may be due to something else. However, I just can't get past mdbook not having the ability to have non-numbered chapters in the sidebar - this is a pet peeve, but it is something I'd like.
I don't plan on having any interactive stuff for the moment, that's why I want a static site generator.

Considering your needs, Quarto might be the better option for you. It's more flexible when it comes to organizing content, which is important since you want both numbered and non-numbered chapters. While Quarto might be slightly heavier than mdbook, you can still optimize it for mobile devices, ensuring it loads quickly even with limited internet. Plus, Quarto supports PDF downloads, which is crucial for your students. Overall, Quarto seems to offer the balance of functionality and customization that you're looking for in a long-term project.
